# How to calculate average of every three consecutive elements skipping one element after every iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Here is a list.

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.
```

I would like to calculate the average of every three consecutive elements. For instance, the output would be:

```
NA NA 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How to do this?

Regards

Comment: did you make an attempt to solve it yourself? Or google it?

Answer (score 6):

Use rolling window:

```
In [117]: s = pd.Series('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'.split())

In [118]: s
Out[118]:
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
dtype: object

In [119]: s.rolling(3).mean()
Out[119]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
7    7.0
8    8.0
9    9.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds :(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, you beat me today quite a few times already... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a non-Pandas solution, you can still get the job done:

```
import statistics
[statistics.mean(x) for x in zip(data, data[1:], data[2:])]
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```